# Getting less than 1 score while trying to check the cosine similarities of same document

Tags: nlp, doc2vec

I have used doc2vec to find the similarities in multiple documents, but when i am checking the same document which i created my model, the score should be '1' right? as the used document and the to be predict document is same. Sadly, I am getting different score when trying to find the similarities. Below is the attached code. Please tell me how to make this right, I can't find what is wrong here. Pleas help me...[doc2vec - calculating document cosine similarity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97bk9.png)

```py
from gensim.models.doc2vec import Doc2Vec, TaggedDocument
df['Tagged_data'] = df['sent_to_word_tokenize_text'].apply(lambda x: [TaggedDocument(d, [i]) for i, d in enumerate(x)])
sadguru_model = Doc2Vec(df['Tagged_data'][0], vector_size = 1000, window = 500, dm = 1, min_count = 1, workers = 2, epochs = 100) 
test_doc = word_tokenize(' '.join([word for word in df['Sentence_Tokenized_Text'][0]])) 
# Sadguru model document 
index0 = sadguru_model.docvecs.most_similar(positive=sadguru_model.infer_vector(test_doc)], topn =1) output: index0 = [(4014, 0.5270981788635254)]
```

output: `index0 = [(4014, 0.5270981788635254)]`

Comment: Below is the code:

from gensim.models.doc2vec import Doc2Vec, TaggedDocument

df['Tagged_data'] = df['sent_to_word_tokenize_text'].apply(lambda x: [TaggedDocument(d, [i]) for i, d in enumerate(x)])

sadguru_model = Doc2Vec(df['Tagged_data'][0], vector_size = 1000, window = 500, dm = 1, min_count = 1, workers = 2, epochs = 100)
test_doc = word_tokenize(' '.join([word for word in df['Sentence_Tokenized_Text'][0]]))  # Sadguru model document
index0 = sadguru_model.docvecs.most_similar(positive=sadguru_model.infer_vector(test_doc)], topn =1)
output: index0 =  [(4014, 0.5270981788635254)]

Comment: Code is impossible to read as non-line-broken comments, so I've added it, with line-breaks, to your question. Note you can always edit your question to add more info with full formatting. Answer forthcoming.

Answer (score 0):

`Doc2Vec` doesn't discover true, unique vectors for every input document. Rather, it progressively learns useful-approximation vectors, using an internal algorithm that itself makes use of a lot of random initialization and random sampling. As a result:

- if your training data includes the same document (same words) twice, with different document-ids, they won't get identical vectors
- re-inferring vectors on a trained model, with the exact same words as an in-training document, won't result in identical vectors to the same original document

For more info, see the [Gensim FAQ questions 11 & 12](https://github.com/RARE-Technologies/gensim/wiki/Recipes-&-FAQ#q11-ive-trained-my-word2vecdoc2vecetc-model-repeatedly-using-the-exact-same-text-corpus-but-the-vectors-are-different-each-time-is-there-a-bug-or-have-i-made-a-mistake-2vec-training-non-determinism).

If your data & parameters are sufficient, then you can expect that two identical documents should have "very close" vectors, and a re-inference of the same document-words creates a vector "very close" to the same document in the original training set. (There's no precise definition of "very close", but in a working model, such same-word documents will be closer to each other than other documents in the training set.)

So you should expect 'high' similarities approaching `1.0`, but *essentially never* `1.0` exactly, unless you've made two identical vectors on purpose with a lot of special effort.

However, you're not even seeing that 'very close' result, because it looks like your training parameters (and probably, training corpus) are way out-of-whack compared to normal or best practices. Specifically:

- A `vector_size=1000` is only appropriate for gigantic datasets, of millions (ideally tens-of-millions) of documents. If you're using vectors larger than your data can fill with meaningful distinctions, your models' results will appear increasingly random - especially in the case of identical or very-similar documents, because now instead of the stochastic, iterative process gradually nudging them to the same 'neighborhood' of values, they could wind up all over the place.
- A `window=500` is unprecedented. The default is `5`, sometimes values up to `20` are used, or occasionally giant values **if and only if* the documents themselves are tiny, such that the effective window is still just "the whole document of a manageable size". On a real-sized corpus with documents over 500 words, `window=500` would be amazingly expensive to calculate & likely result if far-worse vectors than a more typical value.
- A `min_count=1` is almost always a bad idea. Words that appear only once, or a few times, don't have the variety of subtly-varying uses that are needed for `Doc2Vec` (& related algorithms like `Word2Vec`, `FastText`, etc) to learn meaningful representations. Instead, single/rare uses contribute weird nonrepresentative examples, and often just function as noise preventing other words with enough examples from being better-understood. Far more people should be increasing the value over `5`, as their training data grows, than reducing it.
- An `epochs=100` is highly uncommon, mostly used if struggling to squeeze some results from insufficient data by intensively re-training on it. (The cases where that makes the most sense would also be those where, due to small data, you *decrease* the `vector_size` to below the default of 100.) For `Doc2Vec`, epochs of 10-20 is most common in published results.

Try a `vector_size` no larger than the square root of the count of unique documents you have, leave the `min_count` at its default (or at least `2`), leave the `window` at its default (unless you specifically have very-small documents), and try `epochs=20` (unless you have very few documents and find improvement with slightly more).

Then you'll likely find your self-similarity test to return some high value – perhaps `0.9` or more – rather than `0.52`, but still not `1.0`.

Comment: Thank you very much @gojomo for your explanation.I really didn't know that.
 I finally found what i was looking for. I used below parameters:
vector_size=2, dm =1,workers =4, epochs =8
Like you said I was not looking for similarity test to 1.0, but close to that...I did some tuning(tweaking the epochs) and got score exactly 1.0....is it OK??? 
Can you please give me some links where i can learn more about doc2vec and how to tune the hyperparameters based on the documents I have. I browsed the internet but could not find any proper website to tell us how to handle small to large documents..

Comment: Found another problem..
i checked with others documents(completely unrelated)..it is giving value 0.99 and for some documents it is 1.0

Comment: words with no meaning also coming high value like 0.99

Comment: `vector_size=2` is also a nonsense parameter for this sort of model. Unless you have thousands of training documents, there's not much value in using `Doc2Vec`. (It's possible to demo it, a little, with toy-sized dataset of a few hundred docs – but that's not really what the word2vec/doc2vec/etc algorithms are for, and you'll only have weird & frustrating results if using them on tiny datasets.) Also, why pick some random value like `epochs=8`? As mentioned, typical published results often use 10 or 20 epochs, occasionally more (but not less) for smaller data.

Comment: Alas, I don't know of a general parameter-choosing guide to recommend. But two general principles are (1) start with the defaults, and only change them after (a) you've observed results using the defaults for comparison's sake; (b) you have a good understanding/theory of why changing the value is appropriate in your case; (2) follow the values of a *high-quality* working example from elsewhere that's similar to your project, then tweak gradually, making sure your changes are helping at each step.

Comment: (Unfortunately there are a lot of crappy examples online, which vary defaults for unexplained and often unjustifiable reasons, or just go-through-the-motions of each step without ever showing useful results. If some random online "tutorial" doesn't impress you with its explanations & results of clear value, don't copy its code & bad habits!)

Comment: OK..I have 5 documents(each of length 297689, 442547, 99474, 361845 and 5425208), I checked the similarity with tf-idf and it shows like ===============================
[[1.         0.17388752 0.5060977  0.48275114 0.54742754]

 [0.17388752 1.         0.19567724 0.12346468 0.19722829]

 [0.5060977  0.19567724 1.         0.37098741 0.5179885 ]

 [0.48275114 0.12346468 0.37098741 1.         0.44714844]

 [0.54742754 0.19722829 0.5179885  0.44714844 1.        ]]
=====================================
I am not expecting same kind of values from doc2vec, but it should resembles it right??

Comment: You shouldn't expect good `Doc2Vec` results with just a 5-document training set. It requires hundreds of training documents for toy-sized demos that just barely work; tens-of-thousands to millions for typical published work showing real utility. You could potentially train a model on a larger sample of documents, then use that model on a tiny set of documents.

Comment: Still, most published `Doc2Vec` results tend to use documents that are individually dozens to thousands of words (like articles, posts, or web pages) rather than those that are hundreds-of-thousands to millions of words (like books or full websites). It might still give useful results on such larger docs, if properly trained, but I'm not sure, as it's far less common.